# Selecting data from two different tables with case statement

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have 2 tables.

tab1:

| dates. |
| --- |
| 2021-09-30 |
| 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-02 |
| 2021-10-04 |
| 2021-11-15 |

buckets:

| bucket_dates |
| --- |
| 2021-10-01. |
| 2021-10-02. |
| 2021-10-03. |
| 2021-11-03. |

I want to join these two table to get final result like below. (If there is a matching date then it will match and if there is no matching date, then it should read the next highest date from tab1 table. e.g. 2021-10-03 & 2021-11-03 dates).

Result table:

| bucket_dates | final_dates |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01. | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-02. | 2021-10-02 |
| 2021-10-03. | 2021-10-04 |
| 2021-11-03. | 2021-11-15 |

I tried to do this by using join query

```
select a.bucket_dates,
   case when b.dates is null then (select min(c.dates) from tab1 c where c.dates > a.bucket_dates)
      else b.dates end as final_dates
from buckets a left join tab1 b 
 on a.bucket_dates = b.dates;
```

but this query is giving below error
`Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate`

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: Just use subquery with greater than or equal. The case and join are unnecessary then.

Comment: @MatBaillie answer worked.. but can you give small hint on how can we do this using subquery ?

Comment: I originally thought the problem related to using the subquery inside a case expression. This may not work with pyspark but as I stated you overcomplicated the subquery that you wrote. Had you just written `>=` in the subquery would give you the answer all by itself--at least on other platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If pyspark won't allow `>` or `>=` in a correlated sub-query, just use the `MIN()` in the main query...

```
SELECT
  b.bucket_dates,
  MIN(t.dates)   AS final_dates
FROM
  buckets   AS b
LEFT JOIN
  tab1      AS t
    ON t.dates >= b.bucket_dates
GROUP BY
  b.bucket_dates
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! such a simple solution but it didn't come to mind :)